# Get location in a more precise way with Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using the services of google maps, using the function

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition
```

only that sometimes gives me the exact location, other times it gives me another location very far from mine, however in the maps web page When you press the button that your location gives you, it is always accurate.
Do you know how to do it like google? I mean to make it precise, since I need this functionality for a user registry, and I must obtain its exact coordinates.

Sorry if the translation is bad, I'm using the google translator.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular try to use this method I made it and used it in all my projects and it works well

```
function getCurrentPosition(): Observable<Position> {
  return Observable.create((observer: Observer<Position>) => {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (position: Position) => {
          observer.next(position);
          observer.complete();
        },
        (error: PositionError) => {
          console.log('Geolocation service: ' + error.message);
          observer.error(error);
        }
      );
    });

}
```